# Regexp & Grafana: exclusions and string cut

Tags: regex, grafana-variable

I'm using Grafana and Prometheus to create some graphs, but this I believe is fundamentally a regexp (RE2?) question. I am dynamically creating a list of elements and populating a Variable (Query of `label_values(source)` where "source" contains the list of possible results).  The query returns a list like this:

```
udr_foo
udr_owls
dns-baz1
dns-baz399
rpz_c_1.donotuse
rpz_c_1.memosis
rpz_c_1.argylesocks
rpz_c_1.argylesocks3
rpz_c_1.argylesocks_http2
```

I cannot modify the data in the database; I must trim it down with regexp. Currently, I have this RE2 regexp that I bodged together that I apply to the list to do some exclusions:

`/^(?!dns|udr|rpzlog_c_1.donotuse).*/`

This gives me as a result that is partially useful, because it excludes the results I don't want:

```
rpz_c_1.memosis
rpz_c_1.argylesocks
rpz_c_1.argylesocks3
rpz_c_1.argylesocks_http2
```

Question: **How would I modify that regular expression so it gives me a more concise result set by also stripping the leading "rpz_c_1." string component?** As this is embedded in the Grafana tool, I cannot "pipe" multiple regexp instantiations together with a shell - I only get one regexp opportunity to modify the results. This is the set of results that I would like to have returned:

```
memosis
argylesocks
argylesocks3
argylesocks_http2
```

My regexp probably is awful. A more concise way of looking at this might be:

- return all results that contain "rpz_c_1." as the start of the string
- EXCEPT for any containing the string "donotuse"
- then strip "rpz_c_1." from the beginning of each string

Comment: Not sure if it is supported, but you might use a capturing group `^rpz_c_1\.(?!donotuse)(\S+)` https://regex101.com/r/seoQBf/1

Comment: The fourth bird: Sadly, that does not seem to be supported in Grafana. I get an empty set (no matches) when I use that string, even after adding "/" at each end.

Comment: I spoke too quickly (or rather, I cut and pasted too quickly.)  That does indeed seem to give the intended results!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simplify the negative lookahead by starting the match with `rpz_c_1.` After matching the dot, assert what is on the right is not `donotuse`

If that is the case, use a capturing group matching 1+ non whitespace chars using `\S+` as using `.*` would match any char except a newline 0+ times.

```
^rpz_c_1\.(?!donotuse)(\S+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/seoQBf/1)

Comment: Solved!  Next time I'm in .nl, I owe you a beer.

Comment: @The fourth bird, I just came here to see if you are here.