# ignore N/A or None

Tags: prometheus, grafana, grafana-variable

I am using Grafana and Prometheus. How do we exclude N/A or None from the list of values of a variable? The data will be something like

```
N/A
ABC-100
XYZ-200
123ABC
None
456-DGZ
```

I need just need to display all values other than `N/A` and `None` i.e. display only

```
ABC-100
XYZ-200
123ABC
```

I looked at [Regexp & Grafana: exclusions and string cut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61824254/regexp-grafana-exclusions-and-string-cut)
I tried `^(?!N\/A).*`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXbYD.png)
It did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This situation can be approached from two directions:

1. Remove undesired labels on Prometheus' side.
   Depending on situation, this might be implemented in a couple ways. In the simplest case, where you extract values of label `my_label` from metric `my_metric`, you can use query

```
my_metric{my_label!="N/A", my_label!="None"}
```

Demo of similar query [here](https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/graph?g0.expr=up&g0.tab=1&g0.stacked=0&g0.range_input=1h&g1.expr=up%7Bjob!%3D%22caddy%22%2C%20job!%3D%22random%22%7D&g1.tab=1&g1.stacked=0&g1.range_input=1h).

2. Remove undesired labels on Grafana's side.
   As you mentioned yourself for this regex with negative lookaround should be used.
   Expression [`/^(?!None$|N\/A$).+/`](https://regex101.com/r/02clis/1) will filter out values `None` and `N/A` leaving all others as is.
   [image]

Comment: thank you @markalex. I cannot use the first option as there is variable dependency. For the second option, it did not work. I see from the screen capture, that the values are getting filtered. For me, there is no change in the values. Not sure why.

Comment: @dchopp1, what version of Grafana are you using? Also, are you sure there are no additional symbols in variables (like space)?

Comment: Also, I don't know what variable dependency you have, but I can imagine any that will stop you from using that approach. Can you share you current query?

Comment: The version is very old maybe v7.0

Comment: You can see version if you press help menu. It's probably either in top right corner, or bottom left. Also, what about sharing query? I do believe that first approach still might work for you.

Comment: Since, regex doesn't work for me. I would like to go with the other option. Thanks, @markalex